# sed/awk command to match a word in a file and then replace a line below that

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, sh

I have a sample file:

```
- name: my-app
  <<: *foo
  installed: true
  labels:
    code: x.x
    mode: y.y
  set:
    - name: a.b.c
      value: abc-ab1cd2
    - name: d.e.f
      value: ab1cd2
```

I needed sed/awk command to first match the word (my-app) in a file test.yaml and then replace the value (1234 in value: ) for -name: def and also subsequently for the value (abc-1234 in value: ) for -name: a.b.c

I have tried a sed command

sed -i -e '/d.e.f/{ n; s/value: .*/value: 'value-to-change'/g }' test.yaml

and it just replaces the value for -name: d.e.f for all of the apps in my file. Whereas, I actually wanted to just perform the change for one app (my-app)

Comment: Is that YAML? Why not use a YAML parser?

Comment: I have just uploaded a sample of my yaml file

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response !! Can this be possible with an sed command instead of a yaml parser ?

Comment: @Vicky even if you don't have a YAML parser sed would be a bad choice for this as it doesn't understand literal strings and only reads 1 line at a time by default, awk would be a better choice. Your example isn't adequate to test a potential solution with though - you should have a second full block for `- name: my-app2` or similar, and other lines where `d.e.f` appear in a different context and lines where `dxexf` appears in the target context to ensure a string instead of regexp match, etc. It's always far easier to match the string you want than to not match similar strings you don't want.

Comment: @Vicky For a valid YAML sample, you'd also need to either provide the referenced anchor `foo`, or eliminate or manually resolve the reference itself. Maybe just comment it out as it is hardly relevant to the issue at hand.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a YAML parser!

> The reason why you shouldn't use a text parser like `sed` is that the YAML format has a logical structure that is represented by special symbols and formatting (like `-` for sequences, or indentation for hierarchy), which is unknown to text parsers (unless you write a full YAML parser in them). YAML allows various stylings like quotes or compacting subtrees to a single line, etc. Text parsers only see that actual representation, while YAML parsers robustly operate on logical relations, regardless of the formatting.

Here's an example filter that works in a number of command-line YAML processors (see below). `select(.name == "my-app").set[]` traverses to every item under a field named `set`, which in turn is a sibling of a field named `name` with the value of `my-app`. Each of these items is updated by `select(.name == "d.e.f").value = 1234` and `select(.name == "a.b.c").value = "abc-1234"` which set the value of a field named `value` that by itself is a sibling of a field named `name` with a specified value. All of this is wrapped into a `map`, as the top-level structure appears to be a sequence (containing several "apps"), so each of them can be tested for applicability.

```bash
map(select(.name == "my-app").set[] |= (
  select(.name == "d.e.f").value = 1234 |
  select(.name == "a.b.c").value = "abc-1234"
))
```

Use it with [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) as `yq '…' test.yaml`, or with [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) as `yq -y '…' test.yaml`, or with [itchyny/gojq](https://github.com/itchyny/gojq) as `gojq --yaml-input --yaml-output '…' test.yaml`.

Comment: I have just posted the yaml file as a code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response !! Can this be possible with an sed command instead of a yaml parser ?

Comment: Also the value parameter (value: ) has a combination of alphabets and numbers.. just not the numbers. What changed do I need to make in the above command on yaml parser for this work ?

Comment: @Vicky Re "Can this be possible with an sed command instead of a yaml parser": The reason why you shouldn't use a text parser like `sed` is that the YAML format has a logical structure that is represented by special symbols and formatting (like `-` for sequences, or indentation for hierarchy), which is unknown to text parsers (unless you write a full YAML parser in them). YAML allows various stylings like quotes or compacting subtrees to a single line, etc. Text parsers only see that actual representation, while YAML parsers robustly operate on logical relations, regardless of the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^- name:/{h;b}
     /- name: a\.b\.c/{n;G;s/\(value:\).*my-app/\1 abc-1234/;P;d}
     /- name: d\.e\.f/{n;G;s/\(value:\).*my-app/\1 1234/;P;d}' file
```

Copy the app name into the hold space.

If a subsequent line contains the name `a.b.c`, print it and fetch the next line and append the copied app name line.

If that line contains `value:` and also `my-app`, replace the value with the required value and then print the first line only and delete the rest.